# How do I merge two hashes that start with different keys in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, associative-array, perl-hash

I have to hashes as follows:

```
my %hash1 = (
    'modules' => {
        'top0' => {
            'instances' => {
                'sub_top' => {
                    'instances' => {
                        'inst2' => 2,
                        'inst0' => 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);

my %hash2 = (
    'modules' => {
        'sub_top' => {
            'instances' => {
                'inst0' => 0,
                'inst1' => 1
            }
        }
    }
);                                                                   }
```

I need to merge these into one hash. I tried using Hash::Merge but that works only if I start from subtop onwards only.

```
my $merged_hash = merge(\%{$hash1{modules}{top0}{instances}}, \%{$hash2{modules}});
```

Dumping the resulting `$merged_hash` gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'sub_top' => {
        'instances' => {
            'inst2' => 2,
            'inst0' => 0,
            'inst1' => 1
        }
    }
};
```

But I miss the top part of hash1:

```
'modules' => {
    'top0' => {
        'instances' => {
```

Desired hash after merging should be like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'modules' => {
        'top0' => {
            'instances' => {
                'sub_top' => {
                    'instances' => {
                        'inst2' => 2,
                        'inst0' => 0,
                        'inst1' => 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: the Data::Printer package displays much better than the standard Data::Dump, especially for complicated hashes like the one that you have

Answer (score 3):

One of possible ways to merge hashes on predefined key. See if it satisfies your expectation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my %hash1 = (
    'modules' => {
        'top0' => {
            'instances' => {
                'sub_top' => {
                    'instances' => {
                        'inst2' => 2,
                        'inst0' => 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);

my %hash2 = (
    'modules' => {
        'sub_top' => {
            'instances' => {
                'inst0' => 0,
                'inst1' => 1
            }
        }
    }
); 

my $key = 'sub_top';

mergeOnKey(\%hash1, \%hash2, $key);

say Dumper(\%hash1);

sub mergeOnKey {
    my $h1 = shift;
    my $h2 = shift;
    my $k  = shift;

    my $href1 = find_ref($h1,$k);
    my $href2 = find_ref($h2,$k);

    die 'Hash 1 no key was found' unless $href1;
    die 'Hash 2 no key was found' unless $href2;

    merge($href1,$href2);
}

sub merge {
    my $href1 = shift;
    my $href2 = shift;

    foreach my $key (keys %{$href2}) {
        if( ref $href2->{$key} eq ref {} ) {
            merge($href1->{$key},$href2->{$key});
        } else {
            $href1->{$key} = $href2->{$key} unless defined $href1->{$key};
        }
    }

    say Dumper($href1) if $debug;
}

sub find_ref {
    my $href = shift;
    my $key  = shift;

    while( my($k,$v) = each %{$href} ){
        say Dumper($v) if $debug;
        return $v if $k eq $key;
        return find_ref($v,$key) if ref $v eq 'HASH';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
    'modules' => {
        'top0' => {
            'instances' => {
                'sub_top' => {
                    'instances' => {
                        'inst1' => 1,
                        'inst2' => 2,
                        'inst0' => 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice. Could become a module `Hash::MergeOnKey`

Comment: Thanks. That helps. What if the value is array. Can I check if eq 'ARRAY' and merge unique. How to modify this below line in else part of merge subroutine:
 $href1->{$key} = $href2->{$key} unless defined $href1->{$key};

Comment: For simplicity you can experiment with two arrays how you would like to _merge_ them together. Array has elements which in it's own order has indexes. Now you need to decide how you will merge two arrays together: by extending one array with elements from another, or by replacing some elements of one array with elements from another array, or leave only unique elements -- should be the elements ordered by value (number or string). There are many many ways to merge two arrays and you need decide what approach is best for your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Synopsis for Hash::Merge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge#SYNOPSIS), the example shows two hashes that look practically identical in structure. The hashes that you want to merge may have many similarities, but they also have significant differences. So, I would only expect that you can only merge them where their structure is sufficiently "equivalent". Here is the most obvious way that I can think of to get them to merge to the resulting hash you indicate:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;    
use Hash::Merge qw(merge);

my %hash1 = (
    'modules' => {
        'top0' => {
            'instances' => {
                'sub_top' => {
                    'instances' => {
                        'inst2' => 2,
                        'inst0' => 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);

my %hash2 = (
    'modules' => {
        'sub_top' => {
            'instances' => {
                'inst0' => 0,
                'inst1' => 1
            }
        }
    }
);

# Merge the desired parts of the structure
$hash1{modules}{top0}{instances} =
  merge( \%{ $hash1{modules}{top0}{instances} }, \%{ $hash2{modules} } );

# Demonstrate that merge worked as desired
my %desired = (
    'modules' => {
        'top0' => {
            'instances' => {
                'sub_top' => {
                    'instances' => {
                        'inst2' => 2,
                        'inst0' => 0,
                        'inst1' => 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);

is_deeply( \%hash1, \%desired, 'Desired hash is created' );

done_testing();
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher, but is there a way to avoid hard coded non common structure and some how recursively find the key that first matches in 2nd hash excluding the "modules", "instances" like words.

Comment: @VishwasuDeshpande Could you show how you do that with less complicated hashes?

Comment: @VishwasuDeshpande If you can show how to do something like this with a simple example and then show that your more complicated example doesn't work, perhaps that would help us figure out how to bridge the gap between what does work the way you expect and what doesn't work for you.